# How to drools integrate with spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, drools

Step 1: created separate drool project in eclipse mars IDE is working.

Step 2: create maven project and then integrate drool rule engine.Import drools supported files showing compilation errors.

Step 3: pom.xml file drools dependency tag also created.

if anybody know share sample source code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please, publish the source code you have already tried